# Get only one combinations from a list of a list

Tags: python, list, set, unique

How can I get one combination for two sets of numbers?

```
alist =[[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [1, 0], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 3], [3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 2]]
```

I would like to return:

```
alist = [[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. If I understood what you want to do: sort your pairs first then use `set` to remove duplicates. Since lists are not hashable, convert your pairs to tuples before using `set`:

```
set(tuple(sorted(x)) for x in alist)
```

Comment: mark as accepted then please.